# Kendo Editor Template visible conditional

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, kendo-ui

My application is MVC 5, I am using external custom editor for Kendo Diagram.  The template is Kendo MVVM, so can't add any JavaScript.  This works in case it is true:

```
<div data-bind="visible: isClient"> 
    Is Client 
</div>
```

My challenge is how to show a different text if isClient is false

```
<div data-bind="visible: isClient"> 
        Is not Client 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by using invisible

```
<div data-bind="invisible: isClient"> 
        Is not Client 
    </div>
```